# How to get ruby Rational number numerator?

Tags: ruby

From Rational class I got the accessor for denominator.
But I can't find a nominator accessor.

```
Rational(22/7).denominator give 7
```

How do I get 22 similarly?

```
Rational(22/7).**numerator**
```

Comment: Misunderstanding caused this question. I am the author and I want to close this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never heard of the term "nominator" (in this context). The number on the top of the fraction is called the *numerator*.

```
2.1.8 :001 > Rational(22, 7).numerator
 => 22
```

Also, note that `Rational(22/7)` reduces to `Rational(3/1)` since the division is performed first. So in your example, you would actually get 3 and 1 instead of 22 and 7.

Comment: Couldn't remember the word. Yes, I want the reduced form.

Comment: If you want the reduced form, then you'll never be able to get 22. And `Rational(22/7).denominator` gives you 1, not 7 as stated in the question.

Comment: I thought .to_r and Rational are same. Above question formed combining both.

Comment: @MichaelMior `Rational(22.0, 7.0).denominator => 7` ruby reads your number 'type' as integers and will not automatically convert them to floats for you in any calculations. See `22/7` vs `22.0/7`

Comment: Then what would you call someone who nominates someone else for public office?

Comment: @whodini9 I'm not sure what that has to do with my answer or the associated comments.